# How to add constraints to the same set dynamically in JuMP?

Tags: constraints, julia, julia-jump

My question is rather simple. I am using JuMP from Julia and I want to add constraints by separation to a model dynamically and I want all them to belong to the same @constraintref. The thing is that I do not know how many constraints I will end up adding. Is there a kind of push! or append function for adding constraints to the same ref?

Comment: I had similar question. I am not sure if it is possible to replace a constraint with a new one based on the reference name, but if you just need to update the coefficients, you can use JuMP.setRHS as discussed here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/updating-data-in-jump-constraints-iteratively/5467

Comment: In my case, I need to add more constraints "on the go". For example, if in the first iteration I need to add 2 constraints my _@constraintref_ should be _ConsRef[1:2]_. If in the next one I need to add 3 constraints more the _@constraintref_ needs to be updated somehow to _ConsRef[1:5]_ and keep the previously added constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extend the collection, just make your own array (e.g., `ConstraintRef[]`) and `push!` to it instead of using `@constraintref`.

Comment: You are right. In my case  `ConstraintRef[]` and `push!` solve the issue.